# Convert link into coordinates

Tags: google-sheets, geolocation, geocoding

I need to somehow convert google maps link into geographical coordinates( longitude, latitude). Like in one column I have the link and in other two must be the coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

If column A contains the links (starting at A2), you will get the two values (lat & lng) into two separate columns using this formula:

```
=Index(if(A2:A<>"",Split(regexextract(A2:A,"@([^,]*,[^,]*)"),","),))
```

[image: maps]

Comment: What if the links do not contain the lat/lon already in the url string? For example: https://maps.app.goo.gl/DYZim92V68RLKQ2Y9 -- is there a google sheets formula or API call we can make to return lat/lon?